# PostgreSQL UNSIGNED INTEGER (pguint - проблемы с установкой)

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

(Проблема решена)

OS: Ubuntu 17.10.1 x64
PostgreSQL 9.6.6

https://github.com/petere/pguint

```
make
```

> gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith
>   -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/postgresql-9.6-L_AOyy/postgresql-9.6-9.6.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c -o aggregates.o aggregates.c 
> gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes
>   -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/postgresql-9.6-L_AOyy/postgresql-9.6-9.6.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c -o hash.o hash.c 
> gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith
>   -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/postgresql-9.6-L_AOyy/postgresql-9.6-9.6.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c -o hex.o hex.c 
> gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith
>   -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/postgresql-9.6-L_AOyy/postgresql-9.6-9.6.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c -o inout.o inout.c 
> gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith
>   -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/postgresql-9.6-L_AOyy/postgresql-9.6-9.6.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c -o magic.o magic.c 
> gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith
>   -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/postgresql-9.6-L_AOyy/postgresql-9.6-9.6.6=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -c -o misc.o misc.c

and

> /usr/bin/python generate.py 9.6.6 make: /usr/bin/python: Command not
>   found Makefile:37: failed to perform the recipe for the target
>   «operators.c» make: *** [operators.c] Error 127

```
make install
```

> /usr/bin/python generate.py 9.6.6 make: /usr/bin/python: Command not
>   found Makefile:37: failed to perform the recipe for the target
>   «operators.c» make: *** [operators.c] Error 127

Comment: *Из инструкции автора, мне ничего неясно* Попробуйте перевести инструкцию (кроме кода) на свой родной язык и прочитать ещё раз.

Comment: Описанные команды предлагается выполнять в командном интерпретаторе вашей ОС (`cmd` или `ps` в Windows, `*sh` в Linux) при установленном GNU Make, а последнюю отправить на сервер СУБД (например, через `psql`). Вот.

Comment: так спрашивайте конкретно что неясно, или думаете тут кто-то духом своим просвящает?? :-)

Comment: я вообще не знаю как ставить расширения на PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Проблема была решена.

Установил OS: Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Далее установил этот набор инструментов

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall build-essential autoconf automake
```

Следом установил СУБД PostgreSQL 10.1

Шаг 1

```
wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

Шаг 2

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Шаг 3

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Шаг 4

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Шаг 5

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-10
```

СУБД PostgreSQL установлена.

Потом скачал zip архив https://github.com/petere/pguint и распаковал.

Далее открыл терминал из папки распакованного архива, и ввел следующее:

Первое

```
sudo make
```

Второе

```
sudo make install
```

И последним делом отправил на сервер СУБД этот запрос

```
CREATE EXTENSION uint;
```

Готово, у меня заработало.

---

Подумать только, ради этого расширения я поставил линукс... и тут другой вопрос, нужны ли unsigned integer в PostgreSQL? или я просто такой капризный..?

Comment: работает ли с uint8? а то у меня вот валится - https://github.com/petere/pguint/issues/9