# PostgreSQL UNSIGNED INTEGER (pguint - проблемы с установкой на Ubuntu server 16.04)

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Здравствуйте.

Я в этом деле чайник, и мало, что знаю...

На обычную desktop версию все нормально ставится по этому рецепту - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773466/246236

А на сервер версию не хочет...

Выдает:

```
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -We                  ndif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -f                  wrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -W                  error=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/i                  nclude/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/include/x8                  6_64-linux-gnu -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libx                  ml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o aggregates.o aggregates.c

gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -We                  ndif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -f                  wrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -W                  error=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/i                  nclude/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/include/x8                  6_64-linux-gnu -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libx                  ml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o hash.o hash.c

gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -We                  ndif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -f                  wrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -W                  error=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/i                  nclude/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/include/x8                  6_64-linux-gnu -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libx                  ml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o hex.o hex.c

gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -We                  ndif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -f                  wrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -W                  error=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/i                  nclude/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/include/x8                  6_64-linux-gnu -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libx                  ml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o inout.o inout.c

gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -We                  ndif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -f                  wrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -W                  error=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/i                  nclude/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/include/x8                  6_64-linux-gnu -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libx                  ml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o magic.o magic.c

gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -We                  ndif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -f                  wrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -W                  error=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/i                  nclude/postgresql/10/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -I/usr/include/x8                  6_64-linux-gnu -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libx                  ml2  -I/usr/include/mit-krb5  -c -o misc.o misc.c

/usr/bin/python generate.py 10.2
make: /usr/bin/python: Команда не найдена
Makefile:37: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «operators.c»
make: *** [operators.c] Ошибка 127
```

Может, это я натворил что не так?

На десктопе, я скачивал вручную зип архив и распаковыва, потом открывал папку в терминале, и писал маке, маке инсталл...

а на сервере использовал эту команду:

```
git clone https://github.com/petere/pguint.git pguint
```

в корневом каталоге (cd /)

или, тут все нормально? а проблема в другом?

Comment: `make: /usr/bin/python: Команда не найдена` очевидно, питон не установлен... ЗЫ: правильным решением было бы собрать пакет, а не компилировать на сервере...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а как поставить питон? какой командой?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, просто когда я пишу apt-get update, apt-get upgrade там вылазят сообщения о о питоне третей версии... или это не тот?

Comment: Написал `sudo apt-get install python` и все прошло... WTF? а почему на десктопе заработало просто и без пинков..?

Comment: На десктопе, так же очевидно, питон какой-то другой пакет требовал по зависимостям ранее...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, А вы ранее сказали, что `ЗЫ: правильным решением было бы собрать пакет, а не компилировать на сервере`. А можно информации по этому вопросу? просто я не знаю как правильно...

Comment: Тема обширная и в пару слов не уложишься... Для обзора предлагаю ознакопиться с[первым приличным гайдом из гугла](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Но дело это требует понимания процесса сборки программ, желания ознакомится с тем что делают команды и зачем они нужны прежде, чем их вводить, а также умения читать вывод  прежде чем идти с вопросами в интернет.